Analyst per listed security coverage ratio
I've seen somewhere a metric that looks at the total number of issuers at an exchange and divides it by the total number of (sell-side) analysts covering those companies (across brokers/investment banks/other sell-side institutions). The idea is that it can approximate how "efficient" a market should be expected to be. If there are enough analysts to go around multiple times (more than one or even a dozen per security), it is likely that all the important information in the public domain and financial reporting periodical disclosures will be priced in adequately. Conversely, for markets that have less analysts per issuer, then the market might be expected to have some inefficiencies or exploitable price anomalies.
Perhaps there is an official name for this, but I'm not sure.
Question
If I wanted to calculate this, for, say, the NYSE, we see that the number of listed companies is at 2,272 by 2023. However, for the other part of the equation, the number of analysts, that data appears to be disparately located across different brokerages and companies. I'm not trying to do rocket science, so just a rough estimate will suffice, is there anywhere that has a pre-aggregated estimate of analysts covering the NYSE?
Thank you
Listing data at:
https://www.nyse.com/listings

If there are no analysts covering security X, how does it say anything about security Y?

@littleadv I reckon it's more of a rough heuristic, don't know if anyone regards it as impervious

Not convinced it's a heuristic. Being able to compute a number does not guarantee it is useful

Well, whether we like it or not, it is being used. Its epistemological value to society aside, would just want to know if there are aggregated analyst count figures are in the public domain somewhere. That is, after all, the question. We can mutter our misgivings about it in the comments if we like, i'm ok with that.
